# Как найти наибольшую по длине возрастающую последовательность подряд идущих элементов в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Основная задача гласит так: Дан список из 30 элементов. Элементы списка могут принимать произвольные
целые значения. Найти наибольшую по длине возрастающую последовательность подряд
идущих элементов. Если таких последовательностей несколько, можно вывести любую из
них.
помогите если не сложно.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

обычно подобные задачи решаются следующим образом:

1. вы накапливаете временную (рабочую) последовательность
2. как только она заканчивается (следующий элемент меньше или закончились числа), то сравниваете с итоговой последовательностью (которая вначале пустая)
3. и если размер итоговой последовательности меньше - заменяете ее на временную
4. временную обнуляете

в итоге всего кода строчек 5

недостаток только 1 - производительность и требования к памяти, но если вам не гигабайты чисел передают, то терпимо

если же нужен максимально быстрый алгоритм, то вместо последовательностей используются числа начала подпоследовательности и длина подпоследовательности

код в этом случае строчек 10

Comment: Как это будет примерно выглядеть?

Comment: т.е. как примерно будет выглядеть? как я написал так и будет выглядеть: `if len(tmp) > len(max): max = tmp, tmp =[]`